# HIVE create table is hanging - CDH 5.7

Tags: hive, sqoop

Create table script in HIVE is hanging and it is not completing for long time. I am using CDH 5.7, 'show databases' takes time to retrieve the data and finally it showed list of all databases. Below create script i am using:

create table dept 
( dep_id int,
dep_name string
);

Am I missing some configuration settings with related to HIVE? Also I am able to see green image in Cloudera Manager(CM) for HIVE.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Hive metastore was hanging, after restarting Hive service it started working. Thanks for your help in Cloduera community